# lateinit property appContext has not been initialized to get Application Context for ShowToast

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to get application context for showToast but not able to get it here is my code, always getting error :

> lateinit property appContext has not been initialized

```
package com.coding.APPNAVIGATION.MenuAndNavigationDrawer

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context


open class MainApplication : Application() {
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MainApplication.appContext = applicationContext
    }
    
    companion object {
        lateinit var appContext : Context
    }
}
```

```
package com.coding.APPNAVIGATION.MenuAndNavigationDrawer.Utils


import android.widget.Toast
import com.coding.APPNAVIGATION.MenuAndNavigationDrawer.MainApplication

object Utils{

    fun showToast(message : String){
        Toast.makeText(MainApplication.appContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

i want to get application context to run showToast anywhere within the project

Comment: You should never leak the context object so that it would survive the activity. Jus pass it down as a parameter to where it is needed.

Comment: Did you forget to declare this application class in your manifest?

Comment: @Leviathan, the Application Context cannot be leaked, and this pattern is used in numerous Google examples.

Comment: Sorry, mistook it for the activity's context. The application context obviously cannot leak.

Comment: Sorry if i wasted your time the problem is solved by adding the class by name attribute in manifest file like this :- 

android:name="com.coding.APPNAVIGATION.MenuAndNavigationDrawer.MainApplication"